# Date format when creating invoice

Tags: paypal

When I try to create invoice using REST API I get validation error like:

```
"details":[{"field":"items.date","issue":"only date field allowed with (yyyy-MM-dd z) format. (was 2014-12-27T17:01:00Z)
```

I tried with 2014-12-27T17:01:00Z, 2014-12-27Z, and number of others, but I get always the same error.

What kind of format should date be? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went through same and the *only* "format" that worked for me is

```
2014-12-27 PST
```

where the "z" is a time zone. - e.g. `PST` `PDT` `GMT`

This goes for all dates in the `Invoice` - e.g. invoice date, due date

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this worked for me in PHP `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z',$invoiceDate)`