# Paypal REST Api payment_term format

Tags: paypal

I am trying to set the date for payment terms on an invoice using the Paypal REST api.

The format it says is this

> Date on which invoice payment is due. It must be always a future date. Date format yyyy-MM-dd z, as defined in ISO8601.

How do I create this date using PHP, I have tried so many variances and i cannot seem to make it work. Its the 'z' that is throwing me.

Many Thanks.

Liam

Data sent

```
{
    "number":"2",
    "merchant_info":{
        "email":"xxx@xxx.com",
        "business_name":"xxx",
        "phone":{
            "country_code":34,
            "national_number":"969696969"
        },
        "address":{
            "line1":"xxx",
            "city":"xxxx",
            "state":"xxxx",
            "postal_code":"xxxx",
            "country_code":"ES"
        }
    },
    "billing_info":[
        {
            "email":"xxxx@xxx.com",
            "first_name":"xxx",
            "address":{
                "line1":"xxx",
                "city":"xxx",
                "state":"xxx",
                "postal_code":"xxx ",
                "country_code":"ES"
            }
        }
    ],
    "shipping_info":{
        "first_name":"xxx@xxx.com",
        "address":{
            "line1":"xxx xxx xxx",
            "city":"xxx",
            "state":"xxx",
            "postal_code":"xxx ",
            "country_code":"ES"
        }
    },
    "items":[
        {
            "name":"www ",
            "quantity":"1",
            "description":"www",
            "unit_price":{
                "currency":"EUR",
                "value":"11.66"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"www",
            "quantity":"1",
            "description":"www",
            "unit_price":{
                "currency":"EUR",
                "value":"4.67"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"www",
            "quantity":"1",
            "description":"www",
            "unit_price":{
                "currency":"EUR",
                "value":"3.11"
            }
        }
    ],
    "note":"Payment is to made with 7 Days",
    "payment_term":{
        "due_date":"2015-02-10 z"
    },
    "merchant_preferences":{
        "return_url":"http:\/\/google.co.uk",
        "cancel_url":"http:\/\/google.co.uk"
    }
}
```

Response received was error 400.

```
{
    "name":"VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "message":"Invalid request - see details.",
    "debug_id":"8344d1d69459e",
    "details":[
        {
            "field":"payment_term",
            "issue":"either term type or, due date is required."
        },
        {
            "field":"payment_term.due_date",
            "issue":"only date value with 'yyyy-MM-dd z' format is allowed."
        }
    ]
}
```

Just for ease of reading EdSF answered this correctly below

use

```
date('Y-m-d e');
```

Comment: Went through all that and [this was the only format that worked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27670097/304683) _for me_. Hth.

Comment: You are a star that worked a treat, i used date('Y-m-d e') it was perfect thanks

Comment: Cool :) You should answer your own question - to mark it as "answered" (and serve as a reference for others too).

Answer (score 1):

Just for ease of reading EdSF answered this correctly

use

```
date('Y-m-d e');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use like this?

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

Comment: Tried this still no joy, response was 
"issue":"only date value with 'yyyy-MM-dd z' format is allowed."
i also tried date('Y-m-d \z')
Neither worked

Comment: Can you post the code that u tired and what api you trying to use?

Comment: payment_term" =>array("due_date"=>date('Y-m-d \z'))
and 
payment_term" =>array("due_date"=>date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'))

Comment: provide complete api request and response

Comment: @Liam: it'll be better to edit this info into your question, to make it easier for techycommerce to read, parse & respond.

Comment: Hiya sorry i dont understand the answer i put at the bottom of my question. Sorry still new to all this